# show one item in each select dropdown box react

Tags: reactjs

I have a `<Select>` dropdown where I list some options. The problem is that I get all of my options in one row, instead of one option on one row and then the second on the second row and so on.

My code:

```
const value: fruit.value.map(x => x.fruitValue);
const label: fruit.label.map(x => x.fruitLabel);

const options = [{
value: value, label:value,
}]

<Select options={options}/>
```

The interface for fruit:

```
interface Fruit{
value: string;
label:string;
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

But I want the first row to be Banana, then a second row with Apple. The user can only select all the three options at the same time.

Comment: `<Select />` is a react component, not a standard HTML `select` element, but you haven't included the code for it or mentioned the library it comes from (if any). Also, how are those `const <varName>: ...` lines not throwing `SyntaxError`s due to the colons?

Comment: @LionelRowe I wrote in the title that it is react and therefore a react component.

Comment: Yes, but a React component can be anything from `() => null` (yes, that's a valid React component) to a 5000-line monster class with complex stateful logic. If you don't include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it's almost impossible to help you debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because of the `value` and `label` getting wrong. you have to pass like this It's Working.

```js
const fruit = {value: [{fruitValue:'Banana', fruitLabel:'Banana'},{fruitValue:'Apple', fruitLabel:'Apple'},{fruitValue:'Orange', fruitLabel:'Orange'}]}

const result = fruit.value.map(data => {
    return {value: data.fruitValue, label: data.fruitLabel}
})

console.log('result',result)
```

You can passed directly in `options` props in `Select`.

Comment: Thanks!! But the problem is that I do not know how many fruits there may be in the list, therefore I cannot write them all out like you have. The const fruit brings everything from the db, just a simple select *.

Comment: @Alison in `fruit` how the data have arrived can you show ?

Comment: I added some more code! Its just an interface that i use.

Comment: to clarify, I get everything to my Select via the .map function in react. So what I want to do, is to do how you did with the 'const result', but not specifying how many objects/fruits there are in 'const fruit'. Is there a way to loop through it with a foreach-loop?